# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 1, 10], expected input[1, 6000, 1, 301] to have 1 channels, but got 6000 channels instead

Tags: keras, pytorch

I have 12 inputs to be feed into 12 conv2d layer, then flatten and pass into fully connected layer. Each input size is `1*1*301` and total no. of samples I have is 6000. So, my training data is `6000*1*301` for input1 and `6000*1*301` for input2, etc.

Here is my code:

```
class ConvNet1D(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvNet1D,self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(1,10), stride=1, padding=0),  # change this
                    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                )
        self.flat = nn.Flatten()
        #ialize our softmax classifier
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=32*1*3504, out_features=2) #classes =2
        self.logSoftmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
    def forward(self, input1, input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7,input8,input9,input10,input11,input12):
        xe1 = self.features(input1)
        xe2= self.features(input2)
        xe3 = self.features(input3)
        xe4 = self.features(input4)
        xe5 = self.features(input5)
        xe6 = self.features(input6)
        xe7 = self.features(input7)
        xe8 = self.features(input8)
        xe9 = self.features(input9)
        xe10 = self.features(input10)
        xe11 = self.features(input11)
        xe12 = self.features(input12)
        f1=self.flat(xe1)
        f2=self.flat(xe2)
        f3=self.flat(xe3)
        f4=self.flat(xe4)
        f5=self.flat(xe5)
        f6=self.flat(xe6)
        f7=self.flat(xe7)
        f8=self.flat(xe8)
        f9=self.flat(xe9)
        f10=self.flat(xe10)
        f11=self.flat(xe11)
        f12=self.flat(xe12)
        
        #con = torch.cat((f1), 1) #f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12
        combined = torch.cat((f1.view(f1.size(0), -1),
                              f2.view(f2.size(0), -1),f3.view(f1.size(0), -1),
                              f4.view(f1.size(0), -1),f5.view(f1.size(0), -1),
                              f6.view(f1.size(0), -1),f7.view(f1.size(0), -1),
                              f8.view(f1.size(0), -1),f9.view(f1.size(0), -1),
                              f10.view(f1.size(0), -1),f11.view(f1.size(0), -1),f12.view(f1.size(0), -1),), dim=1)
        f3=self.flat(combined)
        fc=self.fc2(f3)
        x=self.logSoftmax(fc)
        return x
```

Training part

```
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001,betas=(0.9, 0.999),amsgrad=True)

#begin training
print("Begin Training")

for e in range(1, EPOCHS):
    # Training
    train_epoch_loss = 0
    model.train()
    
    inputs1=inputs1.to(device)
    inputs2=inputs2.to(device)
    inputs3=inputs3.to(device)
    inputs4=inputs4.to(device)
    inputs5=inputs5.to(device)
    inputs6=inputs6.to(device)
    inputs7=inputs7.to(device)
    inputs8=inputs8.to(device)
    inputs9=inputs9.to(device)
    inputs10=inputs10.to(device)
    inputs11=inputs11.to(device)
    inputs12=inputs12.to(device)
    trainY=trainY.to(device)
    
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    y_train_pred = model(inputs1,inputs2,inputs3,inputs4,inputs5,inputs6,inputs7,inputs8,
                        inputs9,inputs10,inputs11,inputs12)
    
    train_loss = criterion(y_train_pred, trainY.unsqueeze(1))
    
    train_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    train_epoch_loss += train_loss.item()
```

I am trying to do the following equivalent of keras. How should I change my code in pytorch to resolve the error. For the same inputs, this is how I trained the model in keras.

```
train1 = train[:,0:1,:\] # shape is 6000\*1\*301
train2 = train[:,1:2,:]
train3 = train[:,2:3,:]
train4 = train[:,3:4,:]
train5 = train[:,4:5,:]
train6 = train[:,5:6,:]
train7 = train[:,6:7,:]
train8 = train[:,7:8,:]
train9 = train[:,8:9,:]
train10 = train[:,9:10,:]
train11 = train[:,10:11,:]
train12 = train[:,11:12,:]
RawInput1 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput2 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput3 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput4 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput5 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput6 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput7 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput8 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput9 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput10 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput11 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))
RawInput12 = Input(shape=(1,301,1))

model = Model(inputs=[RawInput1, RawInput2, RawInput3, RawInput4, RawInput5, RawInput6, RawInput7, RawInput8, RawInput9, RawInput10, RawInput11, RawInput12], outputs=output)
optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
        
auc = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()
model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', auc])

history = model.fit([train1, train2, train3, train4, train5, train6, train7, train8, train9, train10, train11, train12], trainY, 
                     validation_data = ([val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10, val11, val12], valY), epochs=10000, batch_size=32)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10604\2405727506.py", line 221, in <module>
    y_train_pred = model(trainECG1,trainECG2,trainECG3,trainECG4,trainECG5,trainECG6,trainECG7,trainECG8,

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytorch_symbolic\symbolic_api_2.py", line 22, in call_wrapper_for_api_2
    return __nn_module_old_call__(self, *args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10604\2405727506.py", line 111, in forward
    xe1 = self.features(input1)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytorch_symbolic\symbolic_api_2.py", line 22, in call_wrapper_for_api_2
    return __nn_module_old_call__(self, *args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 217, in forward
    input = module(input)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytorch_symbolic\symbolic_api_2.py", line 22, in call_wrapper_for_api_2
    return __nn_module_old_call__(self, *args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 463, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)

  File "C:\Users\Geerthy.DESKTOP-CUP32GO\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 1, 10], expected input[1, 6000, 1, 301] to have 1 channels, but got 6000 channels instead
```